# CGAL::Polyhedron_3 demo - failing intersection

Tags: intersection, cgal, polyhedra

I started using CGAL demos to find the intersection of two polyhedra. I met a problem when the two polyhedra share some vertices and edges. The program extis with "Segmentation fault" call. I assume the problem refers to the shared vertices, since for other case I see no problem. My polyhedra are e.g. rhombic triacontahedra or truncated tiracontahedra (the latter are concave). Is it a problem of demo program or the CGAL algorithm itself?

Input OFF files I use:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nywdv80yzr0wpxp/henley_3D.off
https://www.dropbox.com/s/slxzfwhchpuix2p/henley_shift_3D.off

I'm using CGAL with Ubuntu 10.04 under VirtualMachine with Win7 x64 as host.

I will be grateful for any help from you.
Best,
Radek

Answer (score 1):

First problem, your polyhedra are inconsistently oriented (which explain the checkerboard coloration when you open them in the demo.

Second problem you have non triangular facets which would not
be a problem for Nef if the vertices of the facets were coplanar
(which is not the case).

To fix this you can use the "Orient polygon soup" plugin and "Inside outside" plugin to fix the orientation.
The plugin "Triangulated facets" will help before creating nef polyhedra.